# Self / automatic / no signing state

Tags: corda

Would it be possible to have a state that doesn't require signing by a counterparty?
My usecase is that there should be pieces of data that everyone has access to, but only the person owning the data can decide the correctness and should thus be the only party signing the state. (Calculations will be done in the contract and checks will be done before creating the state)

Not sure sure if my question is clear, so please let me know if I should elaborate some more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

A transaction is required to be signed by every `Party` listed on every `Command` in the transaction.

So if your transaction's `Command`s only list the owner of the data as a `Party`, the owner of the data will be the only required signer.

Comment: Thank you! Am I then also correct in assuming that I can use the extraRecipients in the finalityFlow to send this data to all other partipants?

Comment: Yes. But note that by default, nodes only store states in which they are one of the `participants`

Comment: Yes, that is one of the reasons for choosing corda. Nevertheless, I need some data to be in every node to be queryable:

Comment: You can use the observer nodes functionality: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html.